# I suggest that he go/goes?

Tags: subjunctives, mandative

> I suggest that he **go** to the doctor as soon as he returns from taking examination.

Book says because the sentence involves suggestion so there should be **go** instead of **goes**. What kind of rule is this?

Comment: In addition to *tense* and *number* verbs have *aspect* and *mood*.  This question relates to mood.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is, 'go' in your sentence is a present [subjunctive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood) form.

There are several possibilities for this sentence:

*I suggest that he go.* (Present Subjunctive. More common in [American English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_English). Not very common in [British English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_English)).
*I suggest that he goes.* (Present Indicative. Quite common in [British English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_English)).
*I suggest that he should go.*

Comment: +1 for including what I suggested. I also see this example there: *"the City Attorney suggested that the case not be closed"*

Comment: @MaulikV: This quite common in BrE.

Answer (score 0):

The original sentence needs to be streamlined, the clause ***“as soon as he returns from taking examination”*** is awkward sounding and filled with redundancies, it's also missing the definite article "the".

> I suggest that he **visit** the doctor as soon as **the** examination finishes.

People do say they [‘go to’ and ‘see’ the doctor](https://www.abc.net.au/education/learn-english/learn-english-what-you-can-say-when-you-visit-the-doctor/8431570), but in a formal statement, which the OP appears to be striving for, replacing the verb *go* with *visit* makes it sound a tad more formal.

As for the subjunctive, it is used far more commonly in the US than in the UK, at least that's what everyone says on ELL and EL&U, see below  [emphasis mine]

> …when we come to the third person singular in the present tense, I understand that **American English distinguishes between the mandative subjunctive** (['She suggested that he go to the cinema'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76578/why-is-american-english-so-wedded-to-the-subjunctive)) **and the indicative** ('She suggested that he goes to the cinema') to express the two meanings.
>   @Barrie England

and

> This is an example of a subjunctive. **The subjunctive form of the verb is frequently used in mandative clauses** (certain clauses which contain the content of an order, desire, suggestion). The subjunctive uses the plain form of the verb. The same form as the bare infinitive. The Original Poster's example *‘I be’* would be grammatical in the following sentences:
>
> - He demanded I be taken out and flogged.
> - **He suggested I be** there before the proceedings commenced.
> - It is essential **that I be kept informed** of any new developments.
>
> [The subjunctive is used more frequently in American English than in British, although it is perfectly normal in both](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209531/can-i-be-ever-be-considered-correct/209566#209566).
>   @araucaria

A British person might well avoid the entire issue and *say*

> He **should** go to the doctor.
>   He **ought to** visit/see the doctor as soon as possible.
>   He **needs to** see/go to the doctor's as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem when I first saw [this](https://mcqsme.com/grammar-mcqs/correction-mcqs/i-suggest-that-he-fix-it-soon/) sentence. When I research the topic. I found that the word "suggest' requires the verb in the subjunctive mode(no past tense and s-ending.)

For Example

I suggest that he go there.

I suggest that he be there on time.

I suggest that he is there on time. (Incorrect)

I suggest you don't be late anymore. (Incorrect)

I suggest you not be late anymore. (Correct)

The gerund can also be used.

I suggest not being late anymore.

Comment: You're repeating what the OP is referring to. The question is: what rule governs this use?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/135892)